# How return document from elasticsearch after update?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am trying to update several document fields and return full document after update.
I use [elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s) 1.3.4, [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) 1.4.3 (as server).

Here is a code:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
object ElasticsearchTester extends App {
  private val settings: Settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "clustername").build()
  private val client: ElasticClient = ElasticClient.remote(settings, ("localhost", 9300))

  val initial = """
    |{
    |   "name":"jojn",
    |   "surname":"olol"
    |}
  """.stripMargin

  val updateString = """
    |{
    |   "surname":"123",
    |   "global": {
    |     "new":"fiedl"
    |   }
    |}
  """.stripMargin

  import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._
  val future = client.execute {
    create index "my_index"
  }.flatMap { r=>
    client.execute {
      index into "my_index/user" doc StringDocumentSource(initial)
    }.flatMap { re=>
      println("Ololo indexed is: " + initial)
      println("Ololo indexed id: " + re.getId)
      client.execute {
        update id re.getId in "my_index/user" doc StringDocumentSource(updateString) docAsUpsert true params  ("fields" -> "_source")
      }.map{res=>
        println("Ololo result is: " + res.getGetResult.sourceAsString())

      }
    }
  }

  Await.result (future, 20.seconds)
  println("Ololo ok")
}
```

Why I get `NullPointerException` in line `res.getGetResult.sourceAsString()`?  It seems that update response do not contains a document after update operation.
Is it possible to return document `_source` from update response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic4s seem has no api in [UpdateDefinition](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/UpdateDsl.scala) (for now 23.07.2015) to set fields. However it's builder support this operation, the code below is like dirty hack, but it works as exepcted, just set fields directly into `_builder`:

```
val updateRequest = update id re.getId in "my_index/user" doc StringDocumentSource(updateString) docAsUpsert true
updateRequest._builder.setFields("_source")
client.execute {
    updateRequest
    }.map { res=>
        println("Ololo result is: " + res.getGetResult.sourceAsString())
    }
}
```

prints

```
Ololo indexed id: AU66n1yiYVxOgU2h4AoG
Ololo result is: {"name":"jojn","surname":"123","global":{"new":"fiedl"}}
Ololo ok
```

**Note**

Elasticsearch **does** [support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_parameters_3) returning fields after update request.

**Updated**

Elastic4s after [this](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/commit/064f12fd6e62d0c377899f9fa781976673520e04) commit support this via `UpdateDsl.includeSource` or `UpdateDsl.setFields` methods.